# Shelosha Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a "deficient" Jewish year (353 days in a regular year or 383 in a leap year), there are 7 "deficient" months of 29 days each. Thus, 203 days of such a year are in "deficient" months.

Answer (score 1):

According to [a document reproduced on JewishGen.org](http://www.jewishgen.org/yizkor/Brzeziny/brz078.html), there were 203 Jews in [Brzezin, Poland,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brzeziny) in 1764.

Answer (score 0):

In Gematria there are interchangeble letters. They are known as AT = Aleph Tof, BASH = Bais Shin, GAR = Gimel Raish, DAK = Daled Kuf, etc.

Gar = 203

Gar, The third day of Pesach (Gimel) will be the first day of the coming Rosh HaShana (Raish)